# How to display elements with variable height on a deck structure

Tags: html, css

The goal is to know if its possible to have somethign like this on pure html and css (no javascript)

Where RT can have a variable amount of text
and AD can also have variable height, so, depending on the case we can have ADs Column can exceed the hight of the RT on the left.

Expected Desktop View:

[Desktop Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1nSL.png)

Expected Mobile View:

[Mobile Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU9KQ.png)

I tried using grids, flex, blocks, even float but on all cases the ADs elements are at the right of the RT element.

As you can see in the following image:

[Wrong Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV2so.png)

I need the right column to grow completely independently of the left column

Comment: Welcome to SO, since SO isn't a code writing service I would recommend checking out [mcve]. On a side note, you can accomplish that by having two columns and in the left column have the RT divs and in the right div have the AD divs and it can be done using float, flex or whatever

Comment: It's possible, you have to use a combination of both flex and grid ordering. It's quite complicated.

Comment: Please show what code you have so far.

Comment: unless you provide your `HTML` structure along with the applied `CSS` we could not help much.